# How do I get SoapClient working with Google App Engine (GAE)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to get a PHP SoapClient working with GAE but can't seem to make it happen.

- I have billing enabled for the project.
- The project works fine locally and on many other servers.
- On GAE I get the error "Could not connect to host" code: "HTTP"

Expected result: "Your input parameters are Test1 and Test2"

### app.yaml

```
application: store-kiosk
version: 2
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

### php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"
```

### index.php

```
<?php
  libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
  $client = new SoapClient('http://www.SoapClient.com/xml/SoapResponder.wsdl',array("trace"=>1));
  try {
    $client->__soapCall('Method1',array('Test1','Test2'));
    echo $client->__getLastResponse();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>Exception: ".print_r($e, true)."</pre>\n";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs for your application make it pretty obvious what's going on - you haven't enabled billing for the app.

```
The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.
```

For the record, both of these work fine for me.

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://www.soapclient.com/xml/SoapResponder.wsdl',
    ['connection_timeout' => 30]);

print_r($client->Method1('foo', 'bar'));
```

and

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://www.soapclient.com/xml/SoapResponder.wsdl',
    ['connection_timeout' => 30]);

$r = $client->__soapCall('Method1',['foo','bar']);
if (is_soap_fault($r)) {
  trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$r->faultcode}, faultstring: {$r->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  print_r($r);
}
```

Both print

```
Your input parameters are foo and bar
```

Comment: I have billing enabled in the 'Developers Console' under the project/app > Settings. It justs has a button to disable billing now. Do I need to enable billing elsewhere? The only billing I have active under the 'Admin Console' is "Google Apps for Business"

Comment: Ok I found another billing option on appengine.google.com under billing status that was not enabled. What is the difference between these two billings? I thought the developer console was a new UI for appengine.google.com am I going to be charged twice? Just waiting for payment method to confirm and will post back here if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Confirmed, all working now. Had to enable billing through appengine.google.com not console.developers.google.com